# How do I cluster the leaf labels of a dendrogram?

Tags: python, matplotlib, dendrogram

I've got a dendrogram and I'd like to be able to make a list or dictonairy of the leaf values with out having to maunually make them

I'm trying to group based on colour. The code below returns an error that the defaultdict is not defined
edit: Now its telling me tuple object is not callable

```
cluster_idxs = defaultdict(list)
for c, pi in zip(den['color_list'], den['icoord']):
    for leg in pi[1:3]:
        i = (leg - 5.0) / 10.0
        if abs(i - int(i)) < 1e-5:
            cluster_idxs[c].append(int(i))

TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-76b947227db4> in <module>()
----> 1 cluster_idxs = defaultdict(list)
      2 for c, pi in zip(den['color_list'], den['icoord']):
      3     for leg in pi[1:3]:
      4         i = (leg - 5.0) / 10.0
      5         if abs(i - int(i)) < 1e-5:

 TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Comment: can you share the entire taceback

Comment: yeah  sure thing

Comment: how are you importing `defaultdict`, because for me it works fine

Comment: Yeah my issue isn't with defaultdict now it's telling me that a tuple isn't callable

Comment: in which line is the error? can you show the contents of `den['color_list'], den['icoord']`

Comment: I'm not sure which line the error is in. I'll add what the dendro returns in to the original question

Comment: Stack won't let me post the contents. It considers it all code and won't let me make an edit that makes the question entirly code

Comment: try putting it two different comments

Comment: {'color_list': ['g',
  'g',
  'g',
  'g',
  'g',
  'g',
  'g',
  'g',
  'g',
  'g',
  'g',
  'g',
  'g',
  'g',
  'g',
  'g',
  'g',
  'g',
  'g',
  'g',
  'g',
  'g',
  'g',
  'g',
  'g',
  'g',
  'g',
  'g',
  'g',
  'g',
  'g',
  'g',
  'g','g','g','g','g','g','g','g','r','r','r','r''r','r','r','r','r','r','r','r','r','r','b']

Comment: 'icoord': [[35.0, 35.0, 45.0, 45.0],
  [25.0, 25.0, 40.0, 40.0],
  [15.0, 15.0, 32.5, 32.5],
  [5.0, 5.0, 23.75, 23.75],
  [55.0, 55.0, 65.0, 65.0],
  [85.0, 85.0, 95.0, 95.0],
  [75.0, 75.0, 90.0, 90.0],
  [60.0, 60.0, 82.5, 82.5],
  [14.375, 14.375, 71.25, 71.25],
  [115.0, 115.0, 125.0, 125.0],
  [135.0, 135.0, 145.0, 145.0],

Comment: [120.0, 120.0, 140.0, 140.0],
  [105.0, 105.0, 130.0, 130.0],
  [165.0, 165.0, 175.0, 175.0],
  [155.0, 155.0, 170.0, 170.0],
  [185.0, 185.0, 195.0, 195.0],
  [162.5, 162.5, 190.0, 190.0],
  [205.0, 205.0, 215.0, 215.0],
  [225.0, 225.0, 235.0, 235.0],
  [210.0, 210.0, 230.0, 230.0],
  [176.25, 176.25, 220.0, 220.0],

Comment: [117.5, 117.5, 198.125, 198.125],
  [255.0, 255.0, 265.0, 265.0],
  [245.0, 245.0, 260.0, 260.0],
  [157.8125, 157.8125, 252.5, 252.5],
  [285.0, 285.0, 295.0, 295.0],
  [275.0, 275.0, 290.0, 290.0],
  [315.0, 315.0, 325.0, 325.0],
  [375.0, 375.0, 385.0, 385.0],
  [365.0, 365.0, 380.0, 380.0],
  [355.0, 355.0, 372.5, 372.5],
  [345.0, 345.0, 363.75, 363.75],
  [335.0, 335.0, 354.375, 354.375],
  [320.0, 320.0, 344.6875, 344.6875],

Comment: [305.0, 305.0, 332.34375, 332.34375],
  [282.5, 282.5, 318.671875, 318.671875],
  [205.15625, 205.15625, 300.5859375, 300.5859375],

Comment: [395.0, 395.0, 405.0, 405.0],
  [252.87109375, 252.87109375, 400.0, 400.0],
  [42.8125, 42.8125, 326.435546875, 326.435546875],
  [415.0, 415.0, 425.0, 425.0],
  [455.0, 455.0, 465.0, 465.0],
  [445.0, 445.0, 460.0, 460.0],

Comment: [435.0, 435.0, 452.5, 452.5],
  [495.0, 495.0, 505.0, 505.0],
  [485.0, 485.0, 500.0, 500.0],
  [515.0, 515.0, 525.0, 525.0],
  [545.0, 545.0, 555.0, 555.0],
  [535.0, 535.0, 550.0, 550.0],
  [520.0, 520.0, 542.5, 542.5],
  [492.5, 492.5, 531.25, 531.25],
  [475.0, 475.0, 511.875, 511.875],
  [443.75, 443.75, 493.4375, 493.4375],
  [420.0, 420.0, 468.59375, 468.59375],
  [184.6240234375, 184.6240234375, 444.296875, 444.296875]],

Comment: sorry for all the comments it is a super long list

Comment: after the line `cluster_idxs = defaultdict(list)` can you check what is the output of `cluster_idxs`, can you just print(cluster_idxs) and how the output?